# Determine the differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Determine the differentiable function $ f:\left [ 1,\infty  \right ]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ for which $ f(1)=0 $ and $ y(f(xy)-f(x))=F(y)+y $ , where $ F $ is a primitive of f.

I tried solving the problem by replacing x with 1, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting $x=1$,

$$yf(y) = F(y)+y$$

Differentiating:

$$f(y)+yf'(y) = f(y)+1 \\ \therefore f'(y) = 1/y \\ \therefore f(y) = \ln y + C$$

$C=0$ since $f(1) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\ln(x)$. $\ln(1)=0$, and:

Recall that $F(x)=\int \ln(x) dx=x\ln(x) -x + C$ (and take $C=0$). Then:

$y (\ln(xy) - \ln(x)) = y\ln(xy/x)=y\ln(y)=F(y) + y$.